# Reuse url requests methods

Tags: python, python-requests, reusability

I have a class offering a lot of similar methods:

```
class Helper:
    BASE_URL = "xxx:xxx"
    @staticmethod
    def get_A():
        url = BASE_URL + "/a?"
        resp = requests.get(url)
        ret_json = json.loads(resp.content)
        return [r["id"] for r in ret_json["people"]]

    @staticmethod
    def get_B():
        url = BASE_URL + "/b/list"
        resp = requests.get(url)
        ret_json = json.loads(resp.content)
        return {r["name"]: r["gender"] for r in ret_json["people"]}


    @staticmethod
    def post_C():
        url = BASE_URL + "/admin/c"
        resp = requests.post(url)
        ret_json = json.loads(resp.content)
        return ret_json["date"]

    ......

    @staticmethod
    def get_Z():
        .......
```

How can I reuse the part `url = BASE_URL + diff_url; resp = requests.get(url); ret_json = json.loads(resp.content)` in these methods and keep them returning different parts of  `ret_json` Or **Just Leave Them as They Are**?

---

### To be clear

How can I combine these methods into **one** like this:

```
def get_something(*arg, **kwargs):
    url = BASE_URL + ...
    resp = requests.get/post(url)
    ret_json = json.loads(resp.content)
    return "different part of ret_json"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a helper function to do things common to those functions. And use `requests.request` to allow requesting via different HTTP methods.

```
class Helper:
    BASE_URL = "xxx:xxx"

    @staticmethod
    def request(method, path):
        url = BASE_URL + path
        resp = requests.request(method, url)
        return json.loads(resp.content)

    @staticmethod
    def get_A():
        ret_json = Helper.request('GET', "/a?")
        return [r["id"] for r in ret_json["people"]]

    @staticmethod
    def get_B():
        ret_json = Helper.request('GET', "/b/list")
        return {r["name"]: r["gender"] for r in ret_json["people"]}


    @staticmethod
    def post_C():
        ret_json = Helper.request('POST', "/admin/c")
        return ret_json["date"]
```

Comment: Sorry for my unclear question, what I want here is only one method to express all these methods. Is it possible?

Comment: It's possible but it's not recommended because they all return completely different objects--`get_A` returns a list, `get_B` returns a dict and `post_C` returns a string. It's a good practice to keep function signatures consistent by having fixed returning data types.

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a method on the class that contains the common parts.  Something like:

```
class Helper:
    BASE_URL = "xxx:xxx"

    @staticmethod
    def _base_get(suffix):
        url = BASE_URL + suffix
        resp = requests.get(url)
        return json.loads(resp.content)

    @staticmethod
    def get_A():
        ret_json = Helper._base_get('/a?')
        return [r["id"] for r in ret_json["people"]]
```

Comment: Sorry for my unclear question, what I want here is only one method to express all these methods. Is it possible?

Comment: Not without a rather unattractive and unwiedly `if ... elif ... else` block.  You can reuse common pieces (like my and the other answer suggest) but you can't have a method return wildly different types (`list`, `dict`, `str`) without some sort of conditional evaluation.  You shouldn't _want_ that anyway - there's no uniform contract in that case.  Callers can't know what to expect.